# does a newer version of andriod has better RAM management?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, ram

i have a rather old device with only 1 GB of RAM and currently runs a very barebone android 4.4.4 which lacks a lot of features. I am thinking of installing a newer version of android in it... is it a good idea? or i would better stick to kitkat? im afraid installing a newer version of android would just slow my device down even more (it is already quite slow in its current state). im sorry for my bad english..

device: Polytron Zap 5 4G 450
processor: qualcomm snapdragon 410, quad core 1.2GHz
graphics: adreno 306
RAM : 1 GB

Comment: If a newer version is available for your device, the answer is maybe. Some newer versions have better RAM management, but this all depends on how the OEM implemented it. I would install the newest version you can and perform a factory reset, then only install essential applications. When significantly changing Android versions a factory reset is recommended, meaning 4.4 to 5.0 should perform a factory reset, 4.4.3 to 4.4.4 it is not necessary. This is not a common device that I am aware of, so I can't really give you an answer besides this comment.

Comment: All that said, 1GB or RAM is 1GB of RAM, that is barely usable by today's standards and no change to the OS is going to significantly impact it's usage. 2GB is considered the bare minimum, with 3+GB recommended. I haven't recommended a device, even a "budget" one, with less 4GB for well over a year.

Comment: According to some tests I read memory consumption and app speed can improve upgrading from Android 4.4 to a newer Android version that uses ART (used by Android 5 and 6). Therefore updating may improve your situation, however I don't think that you will realize a big difference.

Comment: It may be beneficial to upgrade the device, however you might find custom ROMs that have the features you want..  I've found that 1GB Ram is good enough for a Phone.. If you are using it as a gaming machine, then obviously not... It's all about fine tuning your performance, Sometimes a few build.prop tweaks can drastically increase performance ( sometimes triple ) ... Using well thought out memory designation can also significantly increase performance... You may be able to lock your CPU profile on Performance mode and harness the full power.. Or do some over clocking ..